# SAS adding an incremental counter based on a condition

Tags: if-statement, sas, counter, increment

I have the following dataset in SAS

```
Id   date        order   amount
101  5/20/2020     1       25
101  5/20/2020     2       25
101  5/20/2020     3        0
101  5/21/2020     1       25
101  5/21/2020     2       25
```

I need to add a counter only amount=25 based on ‘Id’, ‘Date’ and ‘Order’

```
Id   date        order   amount  Ctr
101  5/20/2020     1       25   1
101  5/20/2020     2       25   2
101  5/20/2020     3        0   0
101  5/21/2020     1       25   1
101  5/21/2020     2       25   2
```

Code:

```
Data want:
Set have;
By id date order;
Ctr+1;
If first.id and first.date and first.order) and amount=25 then ctr=1;
Run;
```

I am not getting the desired result. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You already have an order variable, can you leverage that? `if amount = 0 then ctr=0;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot leverage the order variable for whatever reason, this may work. I suspect if your cases get more complex it may break though.

- Set the counter to 0 at the first of each date or an amount that's
  not 25.
- Otherwise if the amount is 25 increment the counter.

```
data have;
input Id $  date mmddyy10.       order   amount;
cards;
101  5/20/2020     1       25
101  5/20/2020     2       25
101  5/20/2020     3        0
101  5/21/2020     1       25
101  5/21/2020     2       25
;;;


data want;
set have;
by id date ;
if first.date or amount ne 25 then ctr=0;
if amount=25 then ctr+1;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs Id  date    order   amount  ctr
1   101 22055   1   25  1
2   101 22055   2   25  2
3   101 22055   3   0   0
4   101 22056   1   25  1
5   101 22056   2   25  2
```